# setOptions doesn't rebind grid ? kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, dojo, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm trying to rebind my grid using setOptions which seems to be a suitable option

Currently i'm working with `Kendo UI v2014.2.903` and i'm trying to use setOptions but it doesn't reload my grid .

**Code :**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
          { field: "name" },
          { field: "age" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
            { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
        ]
    });

  setTimeout(function(){
    alert('update check')
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.setOptions({
       columns: [
          { field: "name" },
          { field: "age" },
         { field: "code" }
        ],
         dataSource: [
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30,code:1 },
            { name: "John Doe", age: 33,code:11 }
        ]
    });
    grid.setDataSource([
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30,code:1 },
            { name: "John Doe", age: 33,code:11 }
        ]);
  },2000);
</script>
```

sample **[here](http://dojo.telerik.com/anEna)** which shows the issue .

when i update the version to `2016.2.504` setOptions seem to work sample **[here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EqEWo)**.

It would be helpful if someone can throw me some hack to fix the issue i see in 2014 version .

Comment: Looks like a `Kendo UI v2014.2.903` does not support setOptions method

Comment: it does i believe . i can see no undefined error , moreover ; i can see function definition inside js file v2014 . @VivekParekh any workaround . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's probably a bug or a not supported feature for `Kendo UI v2014.2.903`(I'm not sure and I think you should post on telerik forums to get an actual answer. I'm curious too)

But since you wanted some work around/hack. One way could be to modify columns as below :

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var ds = grid.dataSource;

grid.columns = [];
grid.thead.remove();
ds.data([{ name: "Jane Doe", age: 30,code:1 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33,code:11 }]);
```

Here is a [working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/anEna/8)

Comment: well yeah ! i tried this one earlier , thanks for bringing this up +1 . actual problem using this approach (by removing thead) is we cant customize grid columns display before data is rendered .

Comment: anyway , thanks man . i gonna mark this one,  it must be a bug sort of . I would like to post in telerik forums but i'm unable to do that. cheers